# How to add bbc weather in my website?

Tags: asp.net

I am developing a website in asp.net using dotnetnuke cms. I need to add Weather cast report in my website. Can anybody please help me?

Comment: I'm afraid you will have to be more specific... the [BBC Weather](http://www.bbc.co.uk/weather/) website is a website at it's own merit. You're likely interested in just some particular part of it... Or control... You will have to be more specific what you'd like to integrate.

Comment: See http://news.bbc.co.uk/weather/hi/about/newsid_7788000/7788189.stm

Comment: By goggling i am trying to find at least an rss feed for weather.i cant get nothing.i need a widget like element in my html.where to start?

Comment: @RobertKoritnik i am trying to add a search widget in my site.

Comment: BBC Weather RSS feed info: http://www.bbc.co.uk/weather/about/17543675 and http://news.bbc.co.uk/weather/hi/about/newsid_7788000/7788189.stm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once again I agree with all of the above, you have provided no code or information on what you're doing or what you've tried...  have you tried anything or do you want us to provide a solution for you? Anyway, rant over, no more sarcasm... these may help however the BBC Backstage API has been discontinued :

[Using BBC Backstage Weather](http://www.cordinc.com/blog/2008/11/using-bbc-backstage-weather.html)

[Hacking the BBC](http://backstage.bbc.co.uk/)

[BBC News and Weather Vista Gadget](http://backstage.bbc.co.uk/prototypes/)